# How can I speed up my R code?

Tags: r, performance, loops

I'm looping through a large character matrix called `geno.data`. I'm essentially looping two columns of the matrix at a time. It's running very slowly. At the end of the loop, I plan to export `EIGENSTRAT_genofile` to a `.txt` file. I use `Xa` in the rest of the program. How can I make it faster? Thanks

```
geno.data <- matrix(nrow = 313, ncol = 300000, c("a","c","g")) # large matrix
Num_of_SNPs<-ncol(geno.data) /2

compute_MAF<- function(j){
    loci<- NULL
    loci<- table(as.vector(geno.data[,c(2*j-1,2*j)]))
    total_alleles<- sum(loci)
    loci<- loci/total_alleles

    # major and minor allele frequencies for one locus
    major_allele<- names(which.max(loci))
    minor_allele<- names(which.min(loci))

    return(cbind(major_allele, minor_allele))
}

Xa <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(geno.data), ncol = Num_of_SNPs)
EIGENSTRAT_genofile<-c()

for (j in 1:Num_of_SNPs){
    allele<-compute_MAF(j)
    X <- 1 * (geno.data[,c(2*j-1, 2*j)] == allele[2])  # minor allele
    reference_allele_count <- rowSums(geno.data[,c(2*j-1,2*j)]==allele[1], na.rm=TRUE)
    EIGENSTRAT_genofile<- rbind(EIGENSTRAT_genofile,reference_allele_count)
    Xa[,j] <- X[,1] + X[,2] - 1
}
```

Comment: look into the doParallel package. if you have multiple cores on your machine you can improve speed significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are improvements that could be made all over your code, the biggest bottleneck is represented by:

```
    EIGENSTRAT_genofile<- rbind(EIGENSTRAT_genofile,reference_allele_count)
```

You should always avoid growing objects inside a loop. Rather, try to initialize a list before the loop:

```
    EIGENSTRAT_genofile<-vector("list",Num_of_SNPs)
```

Inside the loop, you can assign `reference_allele_count` to an element of `EIGENSTRAT_genofile`:

```
    EIGENSTRAT_genofile[[j]]<-reference_allele_count
```

Then, at the end after the loop, you `rbind` all the elements of the list together through `do.call`:

```
   EIGENSTRAT_genofile<-do.call(rbind, EIGENSTRAT_genofile)
```

Comment: that did the trick. The original was running on a remote server for over 5 hours. I made your corrections, it took a minute and a half on my laptop. Do you see any other bottlenecks or improvements I can make to to get it to run even faster?

Comment: In `compute_MAF` there is no reason to normalize the table, since you are just looking for min and max. Then use `c` instead of `cbind` in the return value. Instead of a list (as I suggested in my answer), you could initialize a matrix (I didn't check your code and don't know if that's possible) and fill each row in the loop. These won't be as a massive improvements as the trick in the answer, but still worth a shot.